# Populate kendo details grid from a collection property of the external grid's model

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-mvc

I have a StudentViewModel that contains ICollection < NotesViewModel >. I would like to show the Students in a Kendo UI grid and the notes for each student in a nested details grid. I can do this just like in the telerik's example: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/hierarchy

I need all detail grids to be initially expanded. This is done very easy using javascript function to expand them. And the problem here is that the server gets called once per each row of the students grid.

**I am looking for a way that all detail grids are populated from the Notes properties of the StudentViewModel on the initial load of the grid, without calling the server for each student. I suppose I have to configure the datasource of the inner grid for some custom way, but how?**

I have currently the following code:

Models:

```
public class StudentViewModel
    {
        private ICollection<NoteViewModel> notes;

        public StudentViewModel()
        {
            this.notes = new List<NoteViewModel>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public DateTime SomeDate { get; set; }

        public ICollection<NoteViewModel> Notes { get; set; }
    }
public class NoteViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Discipline { get; set; }

        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        public double Grade { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;
using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
using Models;

public class KendoController : Controller
{
    private static IQueryable<StudentViewModel> data = new List<StudentViewModel>()
    {
        // TODO: HTML Helper could be created to receive controller, view model and columns
        // done in course 200, tiketing system in exam preparation theme
        new StudentViewModel()
        {
            Id=1,
            Name= "Pesho",
            SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-100)
        },
        new StudentViewModel()
        {
            Id=2,
            Name= "Gosho",
            SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-20)
        },
        new StudentViewModel()
        {
            Id=3,
            Name= "Misho",
            SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-120),
            Notes = new List<NoteViewModel>()
            {
                new NoteViewModel()
                {
                    Discipline = "Math",
                    Grade=4,
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-12),
                    Id=1
                },
                new NoteViewModel()
                {
                    Discipline = "English",
                    Grade=5.36,
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10),
                    Id=2
                },
                new NoteViewModel()
                {
                    Discipline = "BG",
                    Grade=3.22,
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-22),
                    Id=3
                },

            }
        },
        new StudentViewModel()
        {
            Id=4,
            Name= "Borko",
            SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1000),
            Notes = new List<NoteViewModel>()
            {
                new NoteViewModel()
                {
                    Discipline = "IT",
                    Grade=5.66,
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-18),
                    Id=4
                },
                new NoteViewModel()
                {
                    Discipline = "English",
                    Grade=5.16,
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1),
                    Id=5
                },
                new NoteViewModel()
                {
                    Discipline = "BG",
                    Grade=3.22,
                    Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-32),
                    Id=6
                },

            }
        },
        new StudentViewModel()
        {
            Id=5,
            Name= "Ganka",
            SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)
        },
        new StudentViewModel()
        {
            Id=6,
            Name= "Lubo",
            SomeDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-10)
        },
    }.AsQueryable();

    // GET: Kendo
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult GridData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var result = data
            .ToDataSourceResult(request);

        return Json(result);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, StudentViewModel model)
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // add to database
            // same for edit, delete
        }

        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, this.ModelState));
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Update([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request, StudentViewModel model)
    {
        if (this.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // add to database
            // same for edit, delete
        }

        return Json(new[] { model }.ToDataSourceResult(request, this.ModelState));
    }
}
```

View: Index.cshtml

```
@using KendoUIDemos.Models

<h2>Kendo Grid</h2>
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<StudentViewModel>()
    .Name("grKendo")
    .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create().Text("Create Student"))
    .ColumnMenu()
    .Columns(columnsFactory =>
    {
        columnsFactory.Bound(col => col.Id);
        columnsFactory.Bound(col => col.Name);
        columnsFactory.Bound(col => col.SomeDate).Title("Some Renamed Date").Sortable(true);
        columnsFactory.Command(com => com.Edit().Text("Edit Student"));
        columnsFactory.Command(com => com.Destroy().Text("Delete Student"));
    })
    .DataSource(data =>
    {
        data
        .Ajax()
        .Model(m => m.Id(student => student.Id))
        .PageSize(4)
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(st => st.SomeDate))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GridData", "Kendo"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Kendo"))
        .Update(edit => edit.Action("Update", "Kendo"))
        .Destroy(del => del.Action("Destroy", "Kendo"));
    })
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("notes-template")
    .Pageable(pageConfigurator =>
    {
        pageConfigurator.Refresh(true);
    })
    .Sortable(sort =>
    {
        sort
        .AllowUnsort(true)
        .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn);
    })
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)))
</div>
<script id="notes-template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo()
       .Grid<NoteViewModel>()
       .Name("notes_grid_#=Id#")
       .DataSource(ds =>
       {
           //???????????? How should I configure the datasource so that the nested details for every row of the external grid
           //are populated initially from the Notes property of the StudentViewModel without calling the server for each student
       })
    )
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following changes on the view

```
@using KendoUIDemos.Models

<h2>Kendo Grid</h2>
<div>
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<StudentViewModel>()
    .Name("grKendo")
    .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create().Text("Create Student"))
    .ColumnMenu()
    .Columns(columnsFactory =>
    {
        columnsFactory.Bound(col => col.Id);
        columnsFactory.Bound(col => col.Name);
        columnsFactory.Bound(col => col.SomeDate).Title("Some Renamed Date").Sortable(true);
        columnsFactory.Command(com => com.Edit().Text("Edit Student"));
        columnsFactory.Command(com => com.Destroy().Text("Delete Student"));
    })
    .DataSource(data =>
    {
        data
        .Ajax()
        .Model(m => m.Id(student => student.Id))
        .PageSize(4)
        .Sort(sort => sort.Add(st => st.SomeDate))
        .Read(read => read.Action("GridData", "Kendo"))
        .Create(create => create.Action("Create", "Kendo"))
        .Update(edit => edit.Action("Update", "Kendo"))
        .Destroy(del => del.Action("Destroy", "Kendo"));
    })
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("notes-template")
    .Events(ge =>
    {
         ge.DetailInit("grKendo_onDetailInit");
    })
    .Pageable(pageConfigurator =>
    {
        pageConfigurator.Refresh(true);
    })
    .Sortable(sort =>
    {
        sort
        .AllowUnsort(true)
        .SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn);
    })
    .Filterable()
    .Groupable()
    .Editable(edit => edit.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine)))
</div>
<script id="notes-template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo()
       .Grid<NoteViewModel>()
       .Name("notes_grid_#=Id#")
       .Columns(col =>
       {
          col.Bound(p => p.Discipline );
          col.Bound(p => p.Date );
          col.Bound(p => p.Grade);
       })
       .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   function grKendo_onDetailInit(e) {
      var notesGrid = e.detailCell.find("[id^='notes_grid_']").data("kendoGrid");
      if (notesGrid) {
         notesGrid.dataSource.data(e.data.Notes);
      }
   }
</script>
```